# How to fetch an existing Exchange or Queue in EasyNetQ?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, easynetq

I am using EasyNetQ and I am wondering how to fetch an existing `IExchange` and `IQueue` without subscribing beforehand?

In the `IAdvanceBus` I can only see:

- `ExchangeDeclareAsync`
- `QueueDeclareAsync`

But I am not sure really whether those will override an existing queue or exchange with the same name?

Also how can I be sure that that queue or exchange exist before trying to fetch / declare it?

Answer (score 2):

The functions `ExchangeDeclareAsync` and `QueueDeclareAsync` will not override existing exchanges / queues. If an exchange or queue with the given name already exists, it will simply be returned. In fact, exchanges and queues in RabbitMQ are immutable, ie. you cannot change their properties after creating them.

This also means that if you call `Exchange/QueueDeclareAsync` with different properties than the existing exchange or queue, you will get a `RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException` about `PRECONDITION_FAILED` notifying you exactly about what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the management plugin activated in RabbitMQ you can use EasyNetQ's client for the management API. [Documentation](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Management-API-Introduction).

For example:

```
var queues = managementClient.GetQueues();

foreach (Queue queue in queues)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("queue.Name = {0}", queue.Name);
}
```

However you won't override a queue or exchange if you redeclare it. Nothing happens.